# ghci - defaulting confusion

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, monomorphism-restriction

I happened to see some strange behaviour during checking the size (`minBound`,`maxBound`) and "length in decimal representation" of different integral types.

Using GHCi:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let mi = minBound
Prelude|     ma = maxBound
Prelude|     le = fromIntegral $ length $ show ma
Prelude|  in [mi,ma,le] :: [Int]
Prelude| :}
[-9223372036854775808,922372036854775807,2]
                                         ^
```

in the last place I would expect `19`.

My first guess is that `maxBound` defaults to `()` and thus yields `2`, but I don't understand that because `ma` should be an `Int` by the explicit type annotation (`:: [Int]`) - and by referential transparency all symbols named `ma` should be equal.

If I put the statement above in a file and load it into GHCi, I get the correct result.

So why do I get a wrong result?

Comment: I think your first guess is pretty close, `ma`'s type isn't fixed to be `Int` until later so `le` is using `ma :: Bounded a => a` which defaults to `()` in the show. If you do it again with `ma = maxBound :: Int` it should give you 19.

Comment: how can it be that the type is not fixed?

Comment: Any behavior can be confusing when you expect the opposite behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Confusingly, this is still the monomorphism restriction at play (or rather the lack thereof when in GHCi). Since GHCi doesn't have the monomorphism restriction enabled, your definitions of `mi` and `ma` don't get specialized to `Int` as you think they will - instead they stay general as `mi, ma :: Bounded a => a` and the `a` variable gets instantiated twice

- once as `()` in `fromIntegral $ length $ show ma` (as you observed, this is a default)
- once as `Int` in `[mi,ma,le] :: [Int]`

If you want `mi` and `ma` to actually be of type `Int`, annotate them as such directly

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let mi, ma :: Int
Prelude|     mi = minBound
Prelude|     ma = maxBound
Prelude|     le = fromIntegral $ length $ show ma
Prelude|  in [mi,ma,le]
Prelude| :}
[-9223372036854775808,9223372036854775807,19]
```

Or turn on the monormorphism restriction manually in GHCi

```
Prelude> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let mi = minBound
Prelude|     ma = maxBound
Prelude|     le = fromIntegral $ length $ show ma
Prelude| in [mi,ma,le] :: [Int]
Prelude| :}
[-9223372036854775808,9223372036854775807,19]
```

Comment: I thought that this might be due to `MonomorphismRestriction` but I tried to `-XNoMono...` - which is already the default setting in GHCi, and got the incorrect result again

Comment: @epsilonhalbe This is one of the only questions I have answered on SO where someone actually wanted to have the `MonomorphismRestriction` (as opposed to the other way around). :)

Comment: It is probably worth remarking this sort of thing is why the monomorphism restriction is in general a good idea - unless you provide a more general signature or you explicitly have a function (i.e. there are arguments to the left of the `=`), you probably aren't going to expect your `let` binding to be polymorphic. In this case, you don't expect `mi` or `ma` to be polymorphic because of this.

Comment: This confusion might also be avoided with [`MonoLocalBinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#let-generalisation), which prevents `let`-generalization.  Two different anti-confusion solutions to the same problem.