# Instance resolution in code and in GHCI

Tags: haskell

In a haskell file, I write

```
x = 2
```

and load it in ghci via spacemacs / intero

I have the following type :

```
:t x
x :: integer-gmp-1.0.0.1:GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
```

whereas if I just type in 2 I get the expected

```
 :t 2 
 2 :: GHC.Num.Num t => t
```

Is there a way to have the instance resolution be like ghci when editing a file ? of course this bites me when using some other datastucture where it can't find some `Eq` class

Comment: Try disabling the monomorphism restriction in the Haskell source file. Or provide a full type signature for the binding `x`.

Comment: This question is a mirror image of [*ghci - defaulting confusion*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42233527/2751851), so you will find the discussion there relevant.

Comment: yes it's a duplicate of the ghci default.